# Accumulated value

Tags: merge, lookup, powerbi, dax

I am coming across an issue wherein I am trying to lookup a Cost to a file with multiple rows for a project, but it's not working out, as lookup is repeating the cost for all the rows and thereby not providing the correct cost associated with a project. Here is how the file looks in which I am trying to lookup the value:

```
Date    Project
1/08/2017   XYZ
2/08/2017   XYZ
3/08/2017   XYZ
4/08/2017   XYZ
5/08/2017   XYZ
6/08/2017   XYZ
1/09/2017   ABC
2/09/2017   ABC
3/09/2017   ABC
4/09/2017   ABC
5/09/2017   ABC
6/09/2017   ABC
12/10/2017  DEF
13/10/2017  DEF
11/11/2017  IJK
```

And here is the file form which I am trying to lookup the value from:

```
Project Budget
XYZ 200000
ABC 300000
DEF 1000000
IJK 50000
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Also how can I count a project is repeated in the field. I am looking for something like this :

```
Date    Project Count_Projects
1/08/2017   XYZ 6
2/08/2017   XYZ 6
3/08/2017   XYZ 6
4/08/2017   XYZ 6
5/08/2017   XYZ 6
6/08/2017   XYZ 6
1/09/2017   ABC 6
2/09/2017   ABC 6
3/09/2017   ABC 6
4/09/2017   ABC 6
5/09/2017   ABC 6
6/09/2017   ABC 6
12/10/2017  DEF 2
13/10/2017  DEF 2
11/11/2017  IJK 1
```

I really need to figure this out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first question. What is the output that you want to see and what are you currently getting?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, you can create the `Count_Projects` calculated column as follows:

```
Count_Projects =
    CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Dates[Date]),
        FILTER(Dates, Dates[Project] = EARLIER(Dates[Project])))
```

Or you can use a variable:

```
Count_Projects = 
    VAR Project = Dates[Project]
    RETURN CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Dates[Date]),
               ALL(Dates), Dates[Project] = Project)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I also managed to find a work around to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Alexis Olson, I'm not clear as to exactly what output you expect; but, *assuming* that you want to see the same Budget number listed for each respective Project entry (e.g., 200000 for each instance of XYZ, 300000 for each instance of ABC, etc.), here's an answer.

If you've got both tables loaded into PowerBI, *As seen from the right side of the screen in the Data view [image](I named them Table and TableLookup)*:

[image]

If you click Home -> Manage Relationships, you'll see there is a relationship between the two tables:

[image]

If you then click Edit..., you'll see it's a Many to one relationship between the overall table (I called it Table) and the lookup table (I called it TableLookup):

[image]

Anyhow, the point is...there is a relationship between the two tables, and you're going to use it.

Click Cancel.

Click Close.

Click Modeling -> New Column; then, in the formula bar, type:

```
 Budget = RELATED(TableLookup[Budget])
```

and enter. You'll get this:

[image]

Then you can do what Alexis said for counting:

Click Modeling -> New Column; then, in the formula bar, type:

```
 Count_Projects = 
     CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Date]),
         FILTER('Table', 'Table'[Project] = EARLIER('Table'[Project])))
```

*I replaced Alexis's "Date" with "Table" because my table is named Table.*

You'll see this:

[image]